# MySQL CREATE USER does nothing

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a new user in `MySQL 8+`, with the following command:

```
CREATE USER ‘wouter’@’myipadress' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword'; *(of course myipadress and mypassword are just an example).*
```

But all I am getting back in terminal is: `'>'`. And the user isn't created.

Does anybody have any idea how to create this user, without getting this error?

Comment: You cannot use fancy quotes like `‘`. You need straight quotes like `'`.

Comment: You probably just need to terminate the statement with ;

Answer (score 1):

Use:
`CREATE USER 'wouter'@'myipadress' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
You cannot use `‘`.